# Is there a way to display only the day from datetime field in Django?

Tags: html, css, django

My code:

```
<span class="day">{{ post.publish_date }}</span>
```

output:

```
Feb. 10,2020
```

expected output:

```
10
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if the `.pubish_date` is a `datetime` object, you can access the [**`.day`** attribute [python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.day):

```
<span class="day">{{ post.publish_date.day }}</span>
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming publish_date is a date, and not a string, then you could do

```
post.publish_date.day
```

eg

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> n = datetime.now()
>>> print(n.day)
```

Answer (score 2):

One more way to get the date by using [`date`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#date) template filter.

```
<span class="day">{{ post.publish_date | date:"d" }}</span>
```